# How to show that if 0 < $\alpha$ < 1, RP$_\alpha$ = RP using reliability amplification

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Let $0 \le \alpha \le 1$. The complexity classs $\mathsf{RP}_\alpha$ consists of all languages $L$ for which we can find a probabilistic polynomial time Turing machine which satisfies the following conditions:

- $w \in L \Rightarrow \Pr[\text{accept}] \geq \alpha$.
- $w \notin L \Rightarrow \Pr[\text{accept}] = 0$.

We define $\mathsf{RP}$ to be $\mathsf{RP}_{1/2}$.

1. How would I show that if $0 < \alpha < 1$ then $\mathsf{RP}_\alpha = \mathsf{RP}$ using reliability amplification?
2. How would I show that when $\alpha = 1$, $\mathsf{RP}_\alpha = \mathsf{P}$?

Comment: This is a very standard exercise. You can see it worked out in lecture notes and textbooks.

Comment: I believe you can solve question 2 on your own.